# SonarQube Scanner for Gradle is not using sonar.projectKey set for rootProject into Subprojects

Tags: sonarqube

SonarQube Scanner for Gradle(http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Gradle) is not using sonar.projectKey set for rootProject into Subprojects.

When I set

```
sonarqube{
  properties {
    property 'sonar.projectKey', 'AAA'
  }
}
```

into (for one of my multiproject) my root project build.gradle then this key is only set for the rootProject, as all subprojects still use the default projectKey (which is $project.group:$project.name).

Now if the change the projetKey into for the rootProject then the sonar analysis is failing with below given error

```
Caused by: org.sonar.runner.impl.RunnerException: Unable to execute Sonar
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:91)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.run(BatchLauncher.java:75)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.doExecute(BatchLauncher.java:69)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.execute(BatchLauncher.java:50)
        at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.doExecute(EmbeddedRunner.java:102)
        at org.sonar.runner.api.Runner.execute(Runner.java:100)
        at org.sonarqube.gradle.SonarQubeTask.run(SonarQubeTask.java:50)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:63)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFa ctory.java:219)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFact ory.java:212)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFact ory.java:201)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:533)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:516)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
        ... 43 more
Caused by: org.sonar.api.utils.SonarException: Module "com.oracle.emaas.emdi:utl" is already part of project "com.oracle.emaas.static_code_analysis.emdi"
```

You can clearly see that for the second run (with different projectKey), subprojects are still using the same default projectKey hence the sonar analysis fails

**Caused by: org.sonar.api.utils.SonarException: Module "subproject-projectKey" is already part of project "projectkey-for-first-upload"**

Comment: In my setup, I only define sonar.projectKey in the root project and the "gradle sonar" call (called from root) scans and reports through all subprojects and reports all of them to the same project in sonar. I believe, defining sonar.projectKey in multiple projects (root and subproject _are_ different projects!) is never a good idea because they will overwrite each other. see each "gradle sonar" call as an atomic overwrite operation (not incremental)